# Custom AD FS Claim Rule for Email Domain Transformation for Jira Cloud SSO Integration

Tags: single-sign-on, jira, saml, adfs

I'm currently integrating AD FS with Jira Cloud for SSO and facing a challenge with email domain mismatches.

Our Active Directory domain for users is company.local, but our verified domain for Jira Cloud is verifieddomain.com.

I need to create a custom rule within our AD FS claim issuance policy to convert the .local extension in UPNs to our verified domain.

Here's the existing rule snippet I found in the [Jira Cloud documentation for configuring SAML SSO with AD FS:](https://support.atlassian.com/security-and-access-policies/docs/configure-saml-single-sign-on-with-ad-fs/)

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname"), query = ";objectSID,mail,givenName,sn;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to edit this rule (or add a new one) to transform any UPN from user@company.local to user@verifieddomain.com.

Could someone advise how to properly create a custom claim rule that would handle this transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/tips-and-tricks-with-adfs-claims-rules-b0b3d910f804).

The solution to your problem is:

**Replace domain name**

*Problem*

We want to replace one domain name with another.

*Solution*

To replace xxx@somedomain with xxx@anotherdomain:

```
c:[Type == “http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"]
=> issue(Type = c.Type, Value = regexreplace(c.Value, “(?<user>[^\\]+)@(?<domain>.+)”, “${user}@anotherdomain”));
```